# Ожидание потоков в android java

Tags: java, android, firebase

Работаю с `firebase`, появилась задача ожидать завершения потоков, но реализация хромает.

У меня структура такая : обращаюсь по пути `N` получаю массив клиентов (id), этот массив клиентов так же содержит массив информации, который хранится по пути `M`, обращаюсь `M`, получаю информацию, записываю.

Проблема в том, что получение информации по пути `M` происходит асинхронно и мне нужно дождаться ответа. Я такое реализовал в `ios` с помощью `dispatchgroup`, на andoroid попытался использовать `CountDownLatch`, но либо я что-то не так делаю, либо он сюда не подходит. Моя попытка :

```
   void getClients(){
        DatabaseReference ref = dataFirebase.scheduleReference.child(dataFirebase.currentId).child("list");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String,Object> users =  (HashMap<String, Object>) postSnapshot.getValue();

                    getUserInfo(users, new ResultHandler<ArrayList<SectionData>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<SectionData> data) {
                           // to-do
                        }

                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }


   void getUserInfo(final Map<String,Object> users,  final ResultHandler<ArrayList<SectionData>> handler){
        final ArrayList<SectionData> sdata = new ArrayList<SectionData>();
        final CountDownLatch cdl1 = new CountDownLatch(users.keySet().toArray().length);

        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()) {
            String uid = entry.getKey();
            final Map<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue();

            dataFirebase.getInfoAboutUID(uid, new ResultHandler<AUser>() { // обращение к firebase
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AUser newUser) {
                  // to-do with sdata and newUser
                   // handler.onSuccess(sdata);
                    cdl1.countDown();
                }

            });
        }

        try {
            cdl1.await();

            handler.onSuccess(sdata);
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) { }


    }
```

Comment: А вызов `ResultHandler`, в котором сейчас `cdl1.countDown()` вызывается, в принципе происходит? Сейчас вызов `getUserInfo` происходит из потока, который обслуживает события от firebase. И пока вызов `onDataChange` не закончится поток занят и поэтому новые события не будут обрабатываться. Получите deadlock. Я подозреваю, т.к. с андроидом не работал вплотную.

Comment: @RomanKonoval мм, вот оно что, а я голову ломаю, почему так ) Да, с андроидом только начал знакомство. Есть решение данной проблемы ?

Comment: Ожидание тут не нужно. Нужно напрямую вызывать `hanlder` (как вы очевидно пытались, судя по закоментированному коду). Другое дело, что, нужно понимать, что этот вызов не в главном цикле обработки событий и нужно поставить в очередь Runnable, который вызовется из главного цикла.

Comment: @RomanKonoval да, я делал напрямую и все работало, но мне не нравилось обновление данных, первый запуск - все хорошо, меняю данные firebase, вызывается слушатель и происходит магия лагов, по этому и решил сделать с ожиданием, как в ios. 

Если Вас не затруднит, можете привести пример ? а то я не до конца понял, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Да тут собственно нечего описывать, если вы говорите, что напрямую работает. Если это вызывает проблемы, то опишите (с кодом) в новом вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас вызов getUserInfo происходит из потока, который обслуживает события от firebase. И пока вызов onDataChange не закончится поток занят и поэтому новые события не будут обрабатываться. Получается deadlock и вызов ResultHandler, в котором сейчас cdl1.countDown() вызывается, в принципе не происходит.

Нужно вызывать `hanlder` напрямую:

```
dataFirebase.getInfoAboutUID(uid, new ResultHandler<AUser>() { // обращение к firebase
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(AUser newUser) {
    // нужно завернуть в Handler чтоб вызов onSuccess произошел в главном обработчике
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> handler.onSuccess(sdata));
  }
});
```